# Is this considered as a recursion?

Tags: java, recursion

```
 public boolean q0() {

    if(word[0] != 'a') {
        System.err.println("Word not accepted!");
        System.exit(0);
    }

    if(word.length-1 > cont && word[cont] == 'a') {
        cont++;
        return q0();
    }
    else if(word[cont] == 'b') {
        q1();
    }

    return false;
}
```

My code is working fine. But I have to be sure if this is actually a recursion

Comment: yeah, why do you think it's not ?

Comment: Yes it is, Any function calling itself is called recursive function. No matter if it is called only for a single case...

Comment: Recursion is calling e method by itself. In your case you are calling `q0` method inside the definition of `q0`. So you are using recursion

Comment: I never used a recursion before. This is my first code

Comment: Sure, it's "recursive".  http://whatis.techtarget.com/definition/recursion:: "A recursive procedure or routine is one that has the ability to call itself."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is technically recursive, yes, since `q0()` calls itself.

It is flawed, though. It uses an external variable `cont` which changes between invocations. It would be much better to have `cont` be a parameter which is passed between different calls rather than it being mutable external state.

This:

```
cont++;
return q0();
```

would become this:

```
return q0(cont + 1);
```

Also, this branch is unusual:

```
else if(word[cont] == 'b'){
    q1();
}
```

Should that be `return q1();`? My guess is your intention is to forward `q1`'s return value. Or does `q1()` actually have side effects? If it's the latter, that's a huge code smell.